# Effective way to store high frequency (e.g. vibrational) Time Series data

Tags: database, timestamp, time-series, influxdb

I have to store a lot of Time Series data, recorded at very high frequencies.

I should store, for each datapoint:

```
Timestamp|Sensor type|Actual value
```

Now, I am using timestamps in nanosecond precision, for example:

```
2018/10/20 5:41:41.000
```

This particular data is taken at 13 kHz, nearly; so, for each second, I have more than 1k value. The used resolution is not enough.

One "raw" solution was to add an additionar "order" field to each datapoint, in order to rebuild the Time Series in a correct order once retrieved.

I am using InfluxDB, and Chronograf/Kapacitor for real-time visualization/alerting. I would like to insert data (in line protocol, btw) in order to make Chronograf able to show nice plots.

How should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The default InfluxDB precision is nanoseconds - exactly what you claim you need.

While the timestamp you've shown as an example of nanosecond-ness - `2018/10/20 5:41:41.000` - is about million times not-even-close.

These are milliseconds in other words. :-)

So I genuinely don't see the problem here: you just start assemble your line-protocol records with nanosec-precision timestamp - that's it!

Like, `myveryswiftmeasurement,SensorType=precious1 actualvalue=1234.56 9223372036854775806`

P.S. Just don't forget to batch the stuff, (better) do not attempt to write every single line alone.

P.P.S With 13 kHz you probably won't even need nanoseconds, uS precision must be enough.

P.P.P.S. Please let me know if I get you wrong, and further detail your question then.